# PayPal as secondary payment option in Braintree

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

We're currently struggling with Braintree PayPal payment in combination with regular bank transfer via IBAN. Basically, we present two subscription options to the visitor: PayPal (via Braintree) and IBAN transaction.

The PayPal method works fine but when we don't select PayPal but IBAN bank transfer, we're getting the following console error:

[image]

We understand that this is the correct behaviour since the PayPal fields are not filled, **but how is it possible to have PayPal as an optional payment method without throwing an error when the fields are not filled?**

We're using the basic js implemetion via DropUI.

```
<div class="bt-drop-in-wrapper" id="showpaypalfields">
    <div id="bt-dropin" class="paypaldiv"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.27.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var client_token = "123TOKEN";
    braintree.setup(client_token, "dropin", {
        container: "bt-dropin"
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
Both forms are visible on the page instantly, they are not loaded afterwards via Ajax or any kind. So, the PayPal option via Braintree should only validate if for example a checkbox is set. For example, the checkbox given in the screenshot below (toggles visibility of both fieldsets).

[image]

---

**UPDATE #2:**
For anyone interested in the final solution:

```
var btInstance;

$('input#paymentmethod-1').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') == true ) {
        teardown();
    }
});

$('input#paymentmethod-2').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') == true ) {
        setup();
    }
});

function setup() {
    if (btInstance) {
        return;
    } else {
        var client_token = "<ps:braintreetoken />";
        braintree.setup(client_token, "dropin", {
            container: "bt-dropin",
            onReady: function (bt) {
                btInstance = bt;
            }
        });
    }
}

function teardown() {
    if (!btInstance) {
        return;
    }
    btInstance.teardown(function () {
        btInstance = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: We need more info on your UX workflow, are both payment forms visible  at the same time? Are they made visible with an event handler? [Braintree's developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/#validation-errors) show the error message is the [standard response](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/#error-field-objects) when their Drop-in UI form is submitted without card number, cvv, expiration, or postal code information. If you can share your html that shows both payment forms that would help us trouble shoot.

Comment: @Shea I updated my question. But yes, they are on the page at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Drop-in UI is still loaded when you select the Lastschrift payment option, which is why you're receiving the validation errors.

One way to avoid these validation errors is to use the ['teardown' method in the 'onReady' callback](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#leverage-onready) in braintree.js to remove the Drop-in UI if a customer selects Lastschrift.

Alternatively, you can separate each of these payment methods into entirely different form elements on your page.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. :)